# Calculate duration and display in daterangepicker Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, daterangepicker

I am trying to calculate duration between selected days on the calender which is calculating fine but when I click apply button instead of when select end date.

I am using calender from: http://www.daterangepicker.com

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left',
  }, function(start, end, label) {
     document.getElementById('departure_date').value = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     document.getElementById('return_date').value = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

//Calculation of Duration:
var date1 = new Date(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
var date2 = new Date(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24) + 1); 
$('.duration_days').html(diffDays+' Days');
    //console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
```

Duration calculating when I press apply button but I want it to be calculate when end date is selected. Please check attached screenshots:
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QHJt.png)
[Screen Shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFJkb.png)

Comment: enable `"autoApply": true` and then use `apply.daterangepicker` event

Comment: Just added autoApply: true, after opens: 'left', but not sure how to use apply.daterangepicker and where. can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

As Shree Tiwari has explained in the comments you can use the **apply.daterangepicker** event.

> apply.daterangepicker: Triggered when the apply button is clicked, or
>   when a predefined range is clicked

So your final js code is like this:

```js
 
 $(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left',
  }, function(start, end, label) {
     document.getElementById('departure_date').value = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     document.getElementById('return_date').value = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  });
  $('input[name="daterange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) { 
      var date1 = new Date(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      var date2 = new Date(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()); 
      var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24) + 1);                                     
      $('.duration_days').html(diffDays+' Days');
 });
});
```

Comment: can you please tell where to add the above code ? inside the datepicker code or outside in a new function ?

Comment: No it is still not working even not calculating duration if I click apply button

Comment: Yeah i forgot the add it to duration days. Does it work now?